# Temporarily colour Linux Terminal foreground and background text

Tags: linux, colors, terminal

How can I temporarily set the colors of my Linux Terminal? I wish to add to a script, a color setting so that I remember to run the partner script a few minutes later. The color change would be set on in one script and removed in the other and would act as a visible reminder to me.

So the color change needs to be applied after the terminal is started up and needs to stay for all subsequent typing until it is removed by another equivalent command.

My terminal is GNOME Terminal 2.31.3

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: My apologies. I found lots of very similar questions on here with the same tags but none that quite addressed what I was trying to do so I posted mine here too. I didn't realise it was inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to change colors.  VTE (the actual terminal within GNOME Terminal) implements these features (generally from [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/)):

- "ANSI color" escapes (which would be useless to you, since many programs reset those)
- changing the text foreground and background using non-ANSI *dynamic colors* (resetters are rare)
- changing the color palette (again, resetters are rare)

The latter two are documented in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), in the section *[Operating System Commands](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Commands)*:

```
OSC Ps ; Pt BEL
OSC Ps ; Pt ST
```

gives the form of the control sequence, e.g., <kbd>*escape*</kbd><kbd>**`]`**</kbd>*Ps*<kbd>**`;`**</kbd>*Pt*<kbd>*BEL*</kbd>

The *dynamic colors* are described here:

```
      The 10 colors (below) which may be set or queried using 1 0
      through 1 9  are denoted dynamic colors, since the correspond-
      ing control sequences were the first means for setting xterm's
      colors dynamically, i.e., after it was started.  They are not
      the same as the ANSI colors.  These controls may be disabled
      using the allowColorOps resource.  At least one parameter is
      expected for Pt.  Each successive parameter changes the next
      color in the list.  The value of Ps tells the starting point
      in the list.  The colors are specified by name or RGB specifi-
      cation as per XParseColor.
```

and other colors here:

```
        Ps = 4 ; c; spec -> Change Color Number c to the color spec-
      ified by spec.  This can be a name or RGB specification as per
      XParseColor.  Any number of c/spec pairs may be given.  The
      color numbers correspond to the ANSI colors 0-7, their bright
      versions 8-15, and if supported, the remainder of the 88-color
      or 256-color table.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for putting effort into writing what appears to be a comprehensive answer. I'm sorry to say I don't understand it. Is it possible you could add one example of what I would type into my terminal to change the foreground say. I'm not a particularly experienced Linux user.